# How to check if a Observable is end?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I want check if a observable is end to store in database the final result.

**Example:**

```
fn () {
    return new Observable( observer => {
        observer.next(1);
        observer.next(2);
        observer.next(3);
        observer.complete(4);
    });
}

fn().subscribe( status => {
    if (this.isEnd()) { // How to check if end???
        //...
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found a solution:
You can use `finally` method.

**Example:**

```
fn () {
    return new Observable( observer => {
        observer.next(1);
        observer.next(2);
        observer.next(3);
        observer.complete(4);
    });
}

fn().finally(() => {
    console.info('End..');
}).subscribe( status => {
    if (this.isEnd()) { // How to check if end???
        //...
    }
})
```